# Django Admin Search field reverse lookup

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I have following models:

```
class Policy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Policies'

class Statement(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    policy = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Policy,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='statements'
    )
    action = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    resource = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

and following simple model admin:

```
class PolicyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [StatementInline]
    search_fields = [name,]
    class Meta:
        model = Policy
```

What I want to achieve is to enable search functionality on Policy change list, through which **I can search Policy with the name field of Statement model** in addition to policy name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@admin.register(Policy)
class ExapmleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ("statements__name",)
    class Meta:
        model = Policy

admin.site.register(Statement)
```

On your admin.py file. You can search Policy with the name field of Statement model like this.